# Extract Data Loop Error

Tags: excel, vba

- 1.I am trying to extract data based on column D having "Y". Data Sample File is as follows.

  2. [![Extract Data][1]][1]

     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnS8i.jpg I am new to VBA and have
     adopted the code from web for my purpose. It is not working and gives
     error Subscript out of range on the following code line.

If vArray(i, 4) = "Y" Then

3. My VBA Code as follows

   ```
    Sub Extract_Values()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim startRow As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim vArray As Variant
    Dim vNewArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim Counter1 As Integer, Counter2 As Integer

    startRow = 2
    Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1")

   With wks
     lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     vArray = .Range("A" & startRow & ":B" & lastRow).Value2
    For i = 1 To UBound(vArray)
      If vArray(i, 4) = "Y" Then
       Counter1 = Counter1 + 1
      End If
    Next i
   ReDim vNewArray(1 To Counter1, 1 To 2)
   For j = 1 To UBound(vArray)
    If vArray(j, 4) = "Y" Then
       Counter2 = Counter2 + 1
       vNewArray(Counter2, 1) = vArray(j, 1)
       vNewArray(Counter2, 2) = vArray(j, 2)
    End If
    Next
   End With

    Range("B" & startRow & ":C" & startRow + Counter1 - 1) = vNewArray

   End Sub
   ```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I am sorry, I should have mentioned that I have adopted code from rwilson post mentioning thread reference. I apologize for the same.

Comment: @rwilson Made the suggested change.  .'vArray = .Range("A" & startRow & ":D" & lastRow).Value2.'  It is still giving the same error.

Comment: Did you use the code I uploaded in the answer section? I also changed the last line to Range("E" & startRow & ":F" & startRow + Counter1 - 1) = vNewArray

Comment: What error are you getting? Where does the error get raised in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry too much about it. ;). Try this:

```
Sub Extract_Values()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim vArray As Variant
Dim vNewArray As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim Counter1 As Integer, Counter2 As Integer

startRow = 2
Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1")

With wks
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    vArray = .Range("A" & startRow & ":D" & lastRow).Value2
    For i = 1 To UBound(vArray)
        If vArray(i, 4) = "Y" Then
            Counter1 = Counter1 + 1
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim vNewArray(1 To Counter1, 1 To 2)
    For j = 1 To UBound(vArray)
        If vArray(j, 4) = "Y" Then
            Counter2 = Counter2 + 1
            vNewArray(Counter2, 1) = vArray(j, 1)
            vNewArray(Counter2, 2) = vArray(j, 2)
        End If
    Next
End With

Range("E" & startRow & ":F" & startRow + Counter1 - 1) = vNewArray

End Sub
```